# Unable to deploy nuxt on digital ocean

Tags: node.js, nginx, nuxt.js, digital-ocean

I have been trying to deploy nuxt on digital ocean for a while now but I have been unable to do so. I have followed the following tutorial to achieve this.

https://kaloraat.com/articles/how-to-deploy-nuxtjs-ssr-app-to-digital-ocean

However, despite numerous efforts the site won't launch. Giving me the following error
*This site can’t be reached\nvlancer.me took too long to respond.*

The following are the steps I followed

1. git clone
2. npm install
3. npm run build
4. npm start
   [image]
5. Then tried to connect through the browser on both vlancer.me and vlancer.me:3000 the error shows up This site can’t be reached.

Even tried reverse proxying through nginx

/etc/nginx/sites-available/vlancer.me(also symlinked /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vlancer.me)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    index index.html;
    server_name vlancer.me www.vlancer.me;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.
All the tutorial skip out on this command
Do this if you have set up reverse proxy through nginx

```
sudo ufw enable 80
```

If not do this

```
sudo ufw enable 3000
```